# Sound does not come on Headphones in Watch Dogs

Tags: pc, watch-dogs

I attach my headphones and listen to some music on my computer and I also played some games, no problems. Fair enough. But as soon as I launch Watch Dogs, the headphone gives no sound and the sound output shifts to my laptop's speaker. I fidgeted with the sound settings to try my luck in fixing it, but failed. What could be the problem? If anyone can guess?

Why does the sound output shift to speaker and not stay with the headphone?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the question I'll assume you're on PC:

- Exit the game
- Go to Windows --> Control Panel --> Hardware and Sound --> Sound --> Playback
- Set your headphones as the default device
- Hit ok, then start the game.

If that does not work, the only option is to go back to that same dialog and disable your laptop speakers altogether *(right-click --> disable)*.